# How do I convert between user data types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to define my own data type and to have a public interface to work on that. But I'm having some trouble with working with a type after it has been created. The example might show what I'm trying to do and what I mean.

```
type Type1 = (Int, Int)

data Type2 = Type2 [Type1] deriving (Show, Read)

add_elem type1 type2 =
        Type2 (type1 : type2)
```

And I get an error that is the expected type of type2 is [Type1] but received a Type2 instead. Which is great - I don't want people messing with the internals of my data types, that is what is so good about strong typing and encapsulation. But I want to be able to do this inside my module to provide the interface.

Am I going about things completely the wrong way? If so, what is the right way to do this; otherwise how do I convert my Type2 to a [Type1] when I want to?

Comment: You left out the type signature for `add_elem`.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez, the type signature isn't necessary because Haskell correctly infers the types

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pattern matching! Basically Haskell has 2 basic operations on data types,

1. Constructors: You already know these, they're basically functions like `Type2 :: [Type1] -> Type2`. You use them to build up various types.
2. Pattern matching: this let's you tear a data structure apart and view its internal fields

   ```
   -- For your case
   toT1s :: Type2 -> [Type1]
   toT1s (Type2 as) = as
   ```

   Here that `Type2 as` is a pattern match binding the value boxed inside `Type2` to `as`.

These sort of functions are actually so common we have some sugar called Records

```
data Type2 = Type2 {toT1s :: [Type1]}
```

This is exactly the same, but saves you some typing.

To learn more about this, I'd recommend a good Haskell tutorial. My favorite is [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#pattern-matching)

Comment: I missed this in the Learn You A Haskell. I knew I was doing something wrong but didn't know what. Thanks this is perfect! (And of course the answer is pattern matching)